# Laravel 5.2 authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've been trying to get the new release (5.2) of Laravel to work with a simple web app. However, I'm having a problem with authentication.

All pages of the app include a navigation view partial which uses Auth::user()->name to display the username in the nav if they are logged in.

In order to do this, I created a pages controller which loads the auth middleware in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This works perfectly if the user is logged in. However, if the user is not logged in, they are requested to login on every page. Even pages like "contact" or "about" which clearly should not require authentication to view.

How can I make pages like "about" always accessible while still being able to access Auth in the nav?

**EDIT:**

*Routes*

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'StaticController@home');
    Route::get('/about', 'StaticController@about');
    Route::get('/contact', 'StaticController@contact');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

*StaticController*

```
class StaticController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        return view('static.home');
    }
    public function about()
    {
        return view('static.about');
    }
    public function contact()
    {
        return view('static.contact');
    }
}
```

*Navigation*

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Comment: You can add the middleware when defining the routes

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want o be able to access Auth in the nav of EVERY page. So if I add middleware per route or for the controller doesn't really matter. The thing is that when I add the middleware, auth is required to view pages which don't need it, I want to be able to read "about" without having to login first, and I also want the nav to be able to access Auth

Answer (score 1):

After deleting everything and installing a fresh copy of Laravel the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Route middleware (can get a bit hard to maintain) https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes
2. Within your view partial you could simply have a conditional statement to check **or** create a method on the Auth facade. This would mean you wouldn't need the conditional. Conditional solution below:

   Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : ''

Comment: Thank you, in my setup I've been using your second solution. I perform a check and then display the name if they are logged in. However, it fails regardless. The error I get is:
    FatalErrorException in Container.php line 700: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: That's a bit funky. In your blade view are you wrapping the solution in {{  }}? Also is 'name' valid?

Comment: Yes, I am using {{ }} and 'name' is valid. It works when viewing pages that also implement the Auth middleware

Comment: The solution should work regardless of using the auth middleware, it is just calling the Auth facade which is independent. Only put the auth middleware on routes you wish to protect from anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

In `/app/Http/Kernel.php`

check to see if you have

```
'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Example

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

    'auth'           => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ....

];
```

---

Now, you may need to re-architect your route to something like this

in your `routes.php`

```
**//Routes (Not Require Log-in)**


Route::get('/home', 'StaticController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'StaticController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'StaticController@contact');
```

---

```
**//Authentication Routes**

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    //................................
    //   More Auth Routes Go in HERE
    //................................

});
```

---

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'update'])
```

the only will be set on the specified method for example